# using multiple twisted socket servers together

Tags: python, sockets, twisted

So I have a single twisted socket server that serves clients and eventually I'll need to add more servers. The problem is that connections to the server are unique and unable to be shared among multiple server instances.

This makes a problem if the servers are behind a load balancer, or if multiple users from a single chat are across multiple server instances, because a message to a chat won't successfully send to everyone.

How would I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It may be a difficult task as balancing load can be improved according to the underlying protocol (like http for web servers).

Are you trying to design a load balancing system for basically any socket based application ? What I mean is that it is one thing to dispatch messages between multiples servers, ensuring correct synchronization, it is another thing to build a dynamic self-balancing system for any communication protocol.

To build your loadbalancer, you can use a "TCP proxy" like HAProxy (http://www.haproxy.org/)

To handle the communication between your application server instances (behind the load balancing server), you can use messaging like zeromq (http://zeromq.org/) or rabbitmq (http://www.rabbitmq.com/). You'll find some common architecture pattern there.

There are python libs for both zeromq and rabbitmq so the implementation within your twisted-based server is not too hard.

Comment: load balancing isn't the issue. if multiple users are communicating and they happen to connect to different servers, there's no way that there messages will reach each other because the connections can't be shared between servers.

Comment: You would have to establish connections between these servers ; this can be easily achieved using zeromq

Comment: @tipu you can try to use fanout rabbitmq exchange and get all messages sent out to all queues so everyone sees everything.